# How can we find text that matches in two columns and find differences of numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data in ColumnA:

```
6,897,661 US
5,646,010 India
4,591,364 Brazil
1,117,487 Russia
777,537 Colombia
768,895 Peru
705,263 Mexico
682,267 Spain
663,282 South Africa
652,174 Argentina
```

I have this in ColumnB:

```
8,217,952 US
7,597,063 India
5,250,727 Brazil
1,422,775 Russia
1,002,662 Argentina
974,449 Spain
965,883 Colombia
952,600 France
868,675 Peru
854,926 Mexico
```

In ColA Argentina is in row 10 and in ColB Argentina is in row 5.  I want to do some kind of lookup and get the text to match, and based on this, find the differences: 1002662-652174.

I tried xlookup and vlookup with wildcard symbols.  I tried isnumber with search.  So far, nothing has worked for me.

I even tried to look for the space, pull out the text, and then do a lookup based on that:

```
=VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A3,LEN(A3)-FIND(" ",A3)),A:A,1,FALSE)
```

When I got to evaluate formula, everything is correct up the the last step, and then I get #NA.  I think it's looking for an exact match, but the cell that's being evaluated has text as well as numbers.

Comment: Have you considered separating each column? Under Data > Text to Column. Then it should be pretty easy to lookup the values for each country and compare the differences.

Comment: I've been wrong many times before, but I think it would be quite complicated to do this with a single formula. Maybe easier to write a process that splits Column A into two columns (number and country) and repeat for column B data, then swap number and country around and use a vlookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways of doing this and less complicated. Like JSmart523's answer. A formula this complicated is bound to fail, and be a pain to find the error. However, I wanted to attempt to do this with one formula as a thought exercise and figured I would share what I came up with? So here you go;

=IFERROR(TEXT(LEFT(INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH((MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,250)),(MID($B$2:$B$11,FIND(" ",$B$2:$B$11)+1,250)),0)),(FIND(" ",INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH((MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,250)),(MID($B$2:$B$11,FIND(" ",$B$2:$B$11)+1,250)),0)),1)-1))-LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)),"#,###")&" "&((MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,250))),(A2))

[image: FindingDifference]

This is an eyesore but I will break it down into parts.

(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,250)) returns everything after the first Space in A2.

[image: Mid]

(MID($B$2:$B$11,FIND(" ",$B$2:$B$11)+1,250)),0)) Does the same for everything in column B as an Array.

[image: MidArray]

Using those as index and match inputs, it returns the column B cell's value that has the matching data following the space.

Wrapped around that is a Left formula, which returns just the numbers from the index and match return.

[image: Left]

We then add a negative sign followed buy the entire formula repeated except, we reverse the cell references. Which just returns the differences between column A and column B.

Around this we need the Text formula to format the number section to have commas again (Text ,"#,###")

Almost to the end we concatenate in a space &" "& and another  ((MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,250))) to add back the words after the space.

The last step is wrapping the formula in an Iferror statement to return the A column value. Due to the cell not appearing in the B column.

Which only leaves out the extra cell in the B column France. Which on this scale isnt an issue but anything larger would be a problem.

I also ran the formula with data that had words as a partial match. IE  apple, and apple orange which did not break the formula.

[image: AppleOrange]

Comment: Nice one.  I really like Index/Match.  Yeah, that's a complex formula.  It's probably going to be a ticking time bomb at some point.

Comment: Yeah haha its hot garbage, but was happy to work out doing an index and match off partial cell data.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Excel 365, here's a Dynamic Array solution

```
=LET(Data1,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),Split1,FIND(" ",Data1),Number1,--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(Data1,Split1-1),",",""),Country1,MID(Data1,Split1+1,999),Data2,FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""),Split2,FIND(" ",Data2),Number2,--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(Data2,Split2-1),",",""),Country2,MID(Data2,Split2+1,999),IFERROR(XLOOKUP(Country1,Country2,Number2,"",0)-Number1,Number1))
```

How it works

```
=LET(
    Data1,FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),                           ' Filter Column A for just data entries
    Split1,FIND(" ",Data1),                              ' Find the space to split on
    Number1,--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(Data1,Split1-1),",",""),   ' Get the number part, remove ",", convert to value
    Country1,MID(Data1,Split1+1,999),                    ' Get the Country
    Data2,FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""),                           ' Repeat for Column B
    Split2,FIND(" ",Data2),
    Number2,--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(Data2,Split2-1),",",""),
    Country2,MID(Data2,Split2+1,999),
    ' The calculation
    IFERROR(                                             ' If Country code is not in Column B, return Column A value
        XLOOKUP(Country1,Country2,Number2,"",0)          ' Lookup Column A code in Column B, Get Column B number
        -Number1,                                        ' Subtract Column A number
        Number1))
```

Comment: I have Office Pro Plus 2013.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use 2 formula then this method works.

1. Find matching cell of A from B using Index Match and keep in C.

> `=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(RIGHT(B1, LEN(B1)-FIND(" ",B1)),RIGHT($A$1:$A$10, LEN($A$1:$A$10)-FIND(" ",$A$1:$A$10)),0))`

2. Separate number from B then minus with Separate number from C. This is in Column D.

> `=LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1))-LEFT(C1,FIND(" ",C1))`

[image: point 1 formula]

[image: point 2 formula]

Comment: Thanks Abdul. I took your idea one step further, and came up with this: =LEFT(B3,FIND(" ",INDEX(B$3:B$200,MATCH(RIGHT(C3, LEN(C3)-FIND(" ",C3)),RIGHT(B$3:B$200, LEN(B$3:B$200)-FIND(" ",A$3:A$200)),0)),1))-LEFT(A3,FIND(" ",INDEX(A$3:A$200,MATCH(RIGHT(B3, LEN(B3)-FIND(" ",B3)),RIGHT(A$3:A$200, LEN(A$3:A$200)-FIND(" ",A$3:A$200)),0)),1))

It has to be entered as an array; Ctrl+Shift+Enter...not just Enter

Answer (score 1):

Click into it, click "Insert - Table" from the ribbon and make sure the "use first row as headers" is not checked.

The ribbon should have changed to the table ribbon. Rename the table to "Example"

In the "Data" ribbon, in the "Get & Transform" section, click "From Table"

This should open up PowerQuery. In PowerQuery, click on Advanced Editor and paste the following:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Example"]}[Content],
    // function that takes text and splits it by the first space
    fTextToRow = (text as text) as list =>
        let
            #"Position of first space" = Text.PositionOf(text, " ")
        in
            {
                Number.FromText(Text.Start(text, #"Position of first space" - 1)),
                Text.Middle(text, #"Position of first space" + 1)
            },
    // function that takes a text list and returns a table where the first column is everything before the first space,
    // and the second column is everything after the first space
    // first column named "Value" and converted to numbers.
    // second column named "Country"
    fSplitValuesIntoTable = (list as list) as table =>
        let
            #"Rows" = List.Transform(list, fTextToRow),
            #"To Table" = Table.FromRows(#"Rows"),
            #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"To Table",{{"Column2", "Country"}, {"Column1", "Value"}}),
            #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns", {{"Country", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}})
        in
            #"Changed Type",
    // column 1 countries and values
    C1Rows = fSplitValuesIntoTable(Source[Column1]),
    // column 2 countries and values
    C2Rows = fSplitValuesIntoTable(Source[Column2]),
    // Sorted, single-column table of all countries.
    Countries = Table.FromColumns({List.Sort(List.Distinct(List.Combine({C1Rows[Country], C2Rows[Country]})))}, {"Country"}),
    #"Merge C1Rows" = Table.NestedJoin(Countries ,{"Country"},C1Rows,{"Country"},"C1Rows",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded C1Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merge C1Rows", "C1Rows", {"Value"}, {"C1Rows.Value"}),
    #"Merge C2Rows" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded C1Rows",{"Country"},C2Rows,{"Country"},"C2Rows",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded C2Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merge C2Rows", "C2Rows", {"Value"}, {"C2Rows.Value"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded C2Rows",{{"C1Rows.Value", "Value 1"}, {"C2Rows.Value", "Value 2"}}),
    #"Added Difference" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Difference", each [Value 2]-[Value 1], Int64.Type)
in
    #"Added Difference"
```

When you click "Close & Load" from the ribbon of the Power Query window, you should see something like this:

[image: Query Result]

### Update 29-OCT-2020

Out of curiosity, I tried Ron Rosenfeld's comments below, and I think I like it better! At the very least, his way of splitting columns is better than the above.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Example"]}[Content],
    fSplit = (table as table, #"Column Name" as text, #"Split Column Suffix" as text) =>
        let
            // Get this because we'll use it more than once
            #"Value Column Name" = "Value" & #"Split Column Suffix",
            // PowerQuery is easier to debug and usually faster if you prune columns you don't need.
            #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(table,{#"Column Name"}),
            // Split the single-column table, Ron's way
            #"Split Column" = Table.SplitColumn(
                #"Removed Other Columns",
                #"Column Name",
                Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false),
                {#"Value Column Name", "Country" & #"Split Column Suffix"}
            ),
            // Convert the Value column from text to integer
            #"Convert Value to Number" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column", {#"Value Column Name", Int64.From})
        in
            #"Convert Value to Number",
    Split1 = fSplit(Source, "Column1", " 1"),
    Split2 = fSplit(Source, "Column2", " 2"),
    #"Merged Split1 & Split2" = Table.NestedJoin(Split1,{"Country 1"},Split2,{"Country 2"},"Split2",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Added Country" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Merged Split1 & Split2",
        "Country",
        each
            if ([Country 1] = null) 
            then List.Single([Split2][Country 2])
            else [Country 1],
        type text
    ),
    #"Expanded Split2[Value 2]" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Country", "Split2", {"Value 2"}, {"Value 2"}),
    // You can change the order of Table.SelectColumns to reorder while you're dropping the other columns in the same step.
    #"Remove Country 1 and Reorder" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Split2[Value 2]",{"Country", "Value 1", "Value 2"}),
    #"Added Difference" = Table.AddColumn(#"Remove Country 1 and Reorder", "Difference", each [Value 2]-[Value 1], Int64.Type),
    #"Sorted by Country" = Table.Sort(#"Added Difference",{{"Country", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted by Country"
```

Comment: Some questions (I'm trying to learn PQ): 1. Why use your splitting method rather than the `Table.SplitColumn` function?  2. Instead of creating a single column table of all the countries, why not just do a `Table.NestedJoin` with the key being the country column?

Comment: 1: I couldn't get Table.SplitColumn to work because of the space in "South Africa"! If you know how to do this, please let me know! It really bugged me! :-)

Comment: 2: I tried that, too. Merging C1Rows with C2Rows adds a line where the country is null, because France. Maybe it would have been better to do that and then use Table.TransformRows to replace `null` with `"France"`? This was fun, but I had ran out of time last evening so I just hurried and finished this in a way I was sure would work.

Comment: 1. If you only list two columns, it will only split into two columns. Then you use the Splitter function to start at the beginning.  eg: `Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"})`  In the UI, there's an option to split by only the left most (or right most or all) delimiter.

Comment: 2. You could do a nestedjoin (Joinkind.fullouter) and then create a new column of countries, replacing nulls with whatever country is in that nested table.

Comment: 2. Agreed! So now we have three ways: **2a:** the way I did it, **2b:** nest, "fix", sort, or **2c:** nest, add new and combined Country column. sort, remove old. What are your thoughts?  I'm thinking 2b would be best in many cases, but Id recommend this be split into *several* queries: "Raw Input", "fTextToRow", "fSplitValuesIntoTable", "C1Rows", "C2Rows", "Countries", and "Output", betting that even though 2b might be better today, 2a as its own query will prove useful later for data validation, power-pivots, or some unexpected future need.

Comment: I don't know which is better, nor how to evaluate it. The way I described it was how I implemented, and the implementation was simple and flexible. Not enough experience to evaluate other differences.

Comment: I don't know how to evaluate it either, but I tried your way and I liked it! I updated my answer.